# Hudson executing just one job non-parallel

Tags: java, continuous-integration, maven, hudson, hudson-plugins

We have a hudson setup with just one executor. we want to get to a point where we can have at least 2 executors. The problem that is stopping us from doing this is a job which cannot be run in parallel.

Explanation:
we have many svn branches configured on hudson. The flow for a particular branch will look like

```
A->B->C
```

In this flow, B writes and deletes data from oracle. we are good, if there is only one branch set up on hudson.

But, we have many svn branches on Hudson. So there could be a another branch with the flow

```
A1->B1-C1
```

Now B and B1 both write and delete data from the **only oracle instance** running on the hudson box, so we are cautious about any data getting messed up, that would be used by the tests . So we don't want to have 2 executors for hudson, which could lead to B and B1 running at the same time.

So is there a solution to this problem?
Can I configure Hudson, not to run B and B1 in parallel, otherwise run two jobs in parallel?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Most likely applications are tied to schemas (one or more).  Could you create "multiple" schemas in Oracle to use in different branches.?

Comment: That is another solution, But, whenever we setup a project on hudson, we have to create a new schema, new configuration. This is a little painful. So I'm looking for something on Hudson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create a slave for each different project.  You can call them SlaveA, SlaveB and SlaveC.  Have them all launch on the same server (main hudson server) with a single executor.

Now for each branch that you have for A,A1,A2.. you can have them build only on SlaveA so that forces thread confinement between each project.

Comment: Can the slaves be configured like a downstream projects? Like Slave B kicks off after Slave A? Because there is dependency between projects A->B->C.

Comment: The slaves themselves cannot, but the jobs still can.  You would have project A1 kick of B1 which then will launch B1 on SlaveB.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Throttle Concurrent Execution plugin. It seems to fit your use case well.